# Not able to deploy VS2017 GCP application to google cloud App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, visual-studio-2017

I have a google cloud account.I am trying to deploy ASP.Net Core application on Google Cloud Platform app engine flex.I am getting an error message saying services need to be enabled. I don't understand what services are to be enabled for deploying this application directly to google cloud

[please see the screen shot of the error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTRDO.png)

Comment: Perhaps you could separate the description of the problem, the screenshot and the error message to improve the readability of your question.

Comment: You may check the relevant documentation [page](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/enable-disable): "Enabling and Disabling Services".

The list of services to enable depends on your application and on the services it requires. 

Have you created a Google Cloud project and enabled billing?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do not post text as images, instead copy-paste the text in your post and format it accordingly.

Comment: enabled  App Engine Admin API  service and is working fine now